# Random 65mb "loop device" in disks and file manager

Tags: disk

What is this? This randomly showed up yesterday after installing salad miner on my server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkKat.png)

This is what is on the "loop device" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY8E6.png)

Comment: Loop devices are created when you install any snap.

Comment: @ChanganAuto how do i get rid of it?

Comment: You don't unless you uninstall the snap software.